# Is emf equal to or proportional to the rate of change of magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I'm slightly confused about Faraday's law. Is it directly proportional or is it equal to the rate of change flux? If it is proportional, what's the proportionality constant? It might seem like a stupid question and I hope I am not wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced emf in a coil is equal to the negative of the rate of change of magnetic flux times the number of turns in the coil. So I guess in your question, the answer would be "proportional to". And if the number of turns is one, then your answer is "equal to". The constant of proportionality is the number of turns in the coil. You will notice a negative sign in front of this constant which is a mathematical statement of Lenz's Law (and also tells us the direction of the current flow).